# Add variables together in a foreach statement based on an ID

Tags: php, google-analytics, opencart

I am using this code to add products to Google Analytics tracking.

```
   <?php foreach($orderProducts as $product) { ?>
  _gaq.push(['_addItem',
      "<?php echo $product['order_id']; ?>",
      "<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>",
      <?php echo json_encode($product['name']); ?>,
      "<?php echo $product['model']; ?>",
      "<?php echo $product['price']; ?>",
      "<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>"
   ]);
```

This works fine for basic products however some products have options and so multiple versions are added to `$orderProducts` with the same model ID. Google Analytics only picks up the first one, and so quantities of the other instances are not tracked.

What I need to do is add all the quantities together for each entry with the same model ID in the array, then remove all but one instance of that model ID with the new 'total' quantity.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through your array, and create a new array containing only one entry for each unique `model`, with the correct `quantity` (untested):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($orderProducts as $product) {
  if (isset($newArray[$product['model']])) {
    $newArray[$product['model']]['quantity'] += $product['quantity'];
  } else {
    $newArray[$product['model']] = $product;
  }
}
```

Then you can loop over the `$newArray` in the same way as you originally did for `$orderProducts`:

```
 <?php foreach($newArray as $product) { ?>
  _gaq.push(['_addItem',
      "<?php echo $product['order_id']; ?>",
      "<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>",
      <?php echo json_encode($product['name']); ?>,
      "<?php echo $product['model']; ?>",
      "<?php echo $product['price']; ?>",
      "<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>"
   ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I can't get this to work. No ID or quantity or outputted.

Comment: This won't output anything, it'll create a new array which will only contain one entry for each unique model, with the correct quantity. I've edited my answer - try that